# Proceed to Radio Button Item Conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

Say I have some radio button items. By default, the first item is checked. If I move to another item, I need to first check if a condition is true. If true, move to new radio button. If false, stay on current radio button.

Expected behavior: "orange" is checked by default. When the user decides to select another radio filter (i.e. "apple"), the handleRadioChange function is triggered. If the conditional is true, then "apple" is checked and "orange" is unchecked. If the conditional is false, then "orange" remains checked as it was before and "apple" remains unchecked as it was before.

I've added code to the snippet above that involves this new case.

```
import React from "react";

class SomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      someVar: false,
      radioValue: "orange"
    };
  }

 fruitBasket = [
  {id: "orange", defaultChecked: true},
  {id: "apple"},
  {id: "banana"}
 ]

  someFunction = () => {
     //does some stuff
 }

  handleRadioChange = () => {
    setRadioValue(e.target.value);         // used within this function, but not shown here

    someFunction().then( someBool => {
     if(someBool !== undefined) {
         this.setState({someVar: true})    // move to new radio button
     } else {
         // ??                             // stay on old radio button!
     }
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
            {fruitBasket.map( (fruit, id) => {
              return(
                <div key={fruit.id} onChange={this.handleRadioChange}>
                   <label>
                      <input 
                         type="radio" 
                         value={fruit.id}
                         defaultValue={fruit.defaultChecked}
                         name="fruit"
                      />
                      fruit.id
                   </label>
                </div>
              )
             })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that "Orange" needs to be selected prior to being able to select "apple" or "banana", and that "apple" needs to be selected prior to "banana"? What does "move to new radio button" mean? Can you clarify the expected behavior? And to be clear, these are supposed to be individual radio inputs, not a radio group?

Comment: No, "orange" is selected by default, but any other subsequent selection can be made in any order. "Moving to new radio button" should say "moving to another radio button, from those 3 options ofcourse". I'll add the expected behavior above. Yes, individual radio inputs.

Comment: I've clarified the expected behavior in the OP.

Comment: Actually, I misspoke. It's a radio GROUP. I've added the "name" attribute the the input component.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes a bit more sense now. I'm still not quite understanding the "moving to another radio button, from those 3 options" part though. Is this part of a form and once an option is selected in the group are you wanting to programmatically focus on the next input in the form (*or similar*)? Either way, can you try to provide a more complete [mcve] for what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it as a controlled component, providing the `checked` for each option instead of using `defaultValue`

```
class SomePage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      someVar: false,
      radioValue: "orange"
    };
    this.fruitBasket = [
      { id: "orange" },
      { id: "apple" },
      { id: "banana" }
    ]
  }

  handleRadioChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;

    if (condition) {
      this.setState({ radioValue: value })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.fruitBasket.map((fruit, id) => {
          return (
            <div key={fruit.id}>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value={fruit.id}
                  checked={this.state.radioValue === fruit.id}
                  onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
                  name="fruit"
                />
                {fruit.id}
              </label>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```